# How does Seam 3 handles the "redirect to capture view" feature after login?

Tags: authentication, seam3

**Here is my use cases.**

I have a login page which is `/public/login.xhtml`. All my other pages are required to log-in before reaching them. They are in `/pages/` directory.

I want that :

1. If my user access to `http://host/myapp/pages/*` it redirects him first to the login page, and then, to the URL he has firstly entered.
2. If my user access to `http://host/myapp/`, it redirects him first to the login page, and then, to `/pages/home.xhtml`.
3. If my user access to `http://host/myapp/public/login.xhtml`, it redirects him first to the login page, and then, to `/pages/home.xhtml`.
4. If my user access to `http://host/myapp/public/login.xhtml` and is already logged in, it redirects to `/pages/home.xhtml`.

---

**What is working currently?**

With Seam 3 (v3.1.0.Final) and the Security + Faces module, my use case **n°1 is automagically working** with :

```java
@ViewConfig
public interface PagesConfig {
    static enum Pages {
        @ViewPattern("/pages/*")
        @LoginView("/public/login.xhtml")
        @LoggedIn
        LOGGED_IN_PAGES,
    }
}
```

My problem is that **I don't understand how Seam's working to do that redirection to the "capture view"**.

With Seam 2, it was easy to understand, in `components.xml` we had

```xml
<event type="org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn">
    <action execute="#{redirect.captureCurrentView}" />
</event>
<event type="org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful">
    <action execute="#{redirect.returnToCapturedView}" />
</event>
```

So we captured the events `notLoggedIn` and `loginSuccessful` to handle that with a `redirect` component.

In Seam 3, I didn't found that configuration : nothing seems to `@Observes LoggedInEvent`, and there is no `Redirect` class...

The **point n°2** is achieved with that `/index.htm` file :

```html
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=pages/home.xhtml">
</head></html>
```

But for my **point n°3**, I've tried solutions which don't fully work.

First I tried that in `login.xhtml` :

```xml
<f:metadata>
    <s:viewAction action="#{loginAction.redirectToHome}" if="#{identity.loggedIn}" immediate="true" />
</f:metadata>
```

And with or without `onPostback="true"`, after I login, I'm still in the login page with that error message (twice) : "*Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id «/public/login.xhtml» for action «#{identity.login}» with outcome «success».*". It's only if I now re-access to `http://host/myapp/public/login.xhtml` that my `viewAction` redirects me to the home.

I also tried that navigation-rule in `faces-config.xml` :

```xml
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/public/login.xhtml</from-view-id>

    <navigation-case>
        <if>#{identity.loggedIn}</if>
        <to-view-id>/pages/home.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

But then, my use case n°1 was disabled : every time I logged-in, I was redirected to the home.

Finally, for my **point n°4**, the `s:viewAction` does the job.

---

So does somebody knows the best practices in order to correctly handle those 4 use cases (which I think are common use cases), especially the point n°3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally here is what I did.

```xml
<f:metadata>
    <s:viewAction action="#{loginAction.redirectToHome}" immediate="true" />
</f:metadata>
```

So I removed the `if="#{identity.loggedIn}"` in order to call my `redirectToHome` method which redirects to 
the `/pages/home.xhtml`.

- If the user is already authenticated, then he is redirected to the home page.
- If he's not, then it is redirected to the home page, which redirects him to the login page thanks to my `@ViewConfig`

Here is the `loginAction` :

```java
public void redirectToHome() throws IOException {
    externalContext.redirect(externalContext.encodeActionURL(externalContext.getRequestContextPath()+"/pages/home.xhtml"));
}
```

**The problem I faced then was when I logged out.**

Here is my logout action :

```xml
<h:commandLink  action="/public/login" actionListener="#{securityAction.logout()}" value="Disconnect" immediate="true" />
```

And the `securityAction.logout()` method :

```java
public void logout() {
    identity.logout();
    if (!conversation.isTransient()) {
        conversation.end();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I was redirected to the login page (thanks to the @ViewConfig I think), **but no `PreLoginEvent` were thrown**, so the Seam `LoginListener.observePreLoginEvent` wasn't called, and so my previous URL wasn't put in session. So when I logged in (immediatly after logout), I was stuck on the login page, but was logged in.

Thanks to [Brian Leathem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264797/brian-leathem) and [he's previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299023/how-does-seam-3-handles-the-redirect-to-capture-view-feature-after-login/9302925#9302925), here is what I did : in my `authenticate` method of my `BaseAuthenticator`, I called that method after authentication :

```java
private void overrideRedirectToLogin() {
    final String PRE_LOGIN_URL = LoginListener.class.getName() + "_PRE_LOGIN_URL";
    final ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    final Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
    String redirectURL = (String) sessionMap.get(PRE_LOGIN_URL);

    if (redirectURL == null) {
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
        redirectURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    }

    sessionMap.put(PRE_LOGIN_URL, redirectURL.replace("/public/login.xhtml", "/pages/home.xhtml"));
}
```

With that solution, my previous URL wasn't set in session, but at least, my user is redirected to the home page.

Answer (score 1):

Use case No. - 1 SeamFaces stores the originally requested viewId in the user Session, then re-routes to that view after the successful login.  It does this by intercepting the navigation from the Seam Security login button, and [fires a PostLoginEvent](https://github.com/seam/faces/blob/develop/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/seam/faces/security/SecurityPhaseListener.java#L361) with the data stored in the SessionMap.

Use case No. 2 - nice solution with the redirect!  You could also do this with a [@UrlMapping in your ViewConfig](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/viewconfig.html#viewconfig.urlrewriting).

Use case No. 3 - Your viewAction solution should work, but I believe you are coming across [SEAMFACES-179](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SEAMFACES-179).  There are a couple of solutions you can use:

1) In your login method, you can manipulate the seesion map stored by the Seam Faces, as demonstrated in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/b3a071f0f95afb25ee42) -- (this solution courtesy of [Cody Lerum](https://github.com/codylerum))

2) Use [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/) to intercept the request for the login view, and rediret you if you are not logged in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm trying to implement your 1) solution, but to do that, I must disable the `LoginListener` of Seam to use mine... and I don't manage to do it :( Here is what I'm facing now : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332311/how-to-use-alternative-extending-a-concrete-class-in-a-webapp

Comment: @AnthonyO. I think you have misinterpreted solution 1).  It is not necessary to replace the LoginListener.  Rather, in your \@Secures method, where the login logic is execute, you can manipulate the  Seam Faces hash-map.  Rest-assured, this is a work-around, and not how things *should* work.