# How to use @Alternative extending a concrete class, in a webapp?

Tags: cdi, jboss7.x

I'm trying to disable 2 observer methods of a class which is in a beans archive jar (more specifically, the class `LoginListener` of Seam 3 Faces module), and use mines instead.

I have a web project, with a beans archive in it :

```
app.war
\- WEB-INF
  \- lib
    \- seam-faces-3.1.0.Final.jar
    |- my-beans.jar
```

In `my-beans.jar` I've got that class :

```java
@Alternative
public class MyLoginListener extends LoginListener {
    @Override
    public void observePostLoginEvent(final PostLoginEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void observePreLoginEvent(final PreLoginEvent event) {
    }
}
```

Then, in `my-beans.jar/META-INF/beans.xml` I activate it :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <alternatives>
        <class>com.mycompagny.MyLoginListener</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

And, same content in `app.war/WEB-INF/beans.xml`.

Here I don't understand why, but it's still the original `LoginListener` `observePostLoginEvent(@Observes PostLoginEvent event)` and `observePreLoginEvent` which are called... does somebody know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to annotate your class also with @Specializes (@Alternative @Specializes)?
According to [Weld Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e4399) this way you can completely "hide" the other bean (with its producers and observers)

Comment: Nice hint. I tried it, and here is the result : `18:56:42,724 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-14) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000047 Specializing bean must extend another bean:  Managed Bean [class com.mycompagny.MyLoginListener] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]`, even if I remove all the `<alternatives>` of `beans.xml` files...

Comment: Actually it seems to be a JBoss 7.0.2.Final bug because I don't have that exception with JBoss 7.1.0.Final (I have another strange exception instead but which is linked with Faces...)